# jQuery - Stop AJAX call after the result returned by it is equal to null

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, performance, model-view-controller

```
      jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true
function compareFilesResult(whlIDs) {
    var result = 0;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/CompareReturnAllResults',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ _IDs: whlIDs }),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != null) {
                compareAllData = data;
                return data;
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            return result;
        },
        fail: function (data) {
            return result;
        }
    });
}
```

Now my Ajax is called always even if the result is NULL ,but I want to be if it is NULL to stop invoking it again.

Comment: where are you calling `compareFilesResult`?

Comment: in the main method ,which executed the whole view.

Comment: Quick comment I'll delete once read (or you can flag once you read it :) ) : your last question got a very negative reaction cause you posted it on meta (not stackoverflow.com, but meta.stackoverflow.com). Meta is used to discuss the main site, its community, its bugs, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just check if it is null then return like:

```
jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true
function compareFilesResult(whlIDs) {
var result = 0;
$.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/CompareReturnAllResults',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ _IDs: whlIDs }),
    success: function (data) {
        if (data == null) { /* try also: if (data === null) */
            return;
        }
        if (data != null) {
            compareAllData = data;
            return data;
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        return result;
    },
    fail: function (data) {
        return result;
    }
});
}
```